# Reporteador BIRT de eclipse, Layout y Master Page

Tags: eclipse, report

estoy trabajando con el **reporteador BIRT de eclipse** y no se la diferencia entre Layout y Master Page a la hora de diseñar un reporte.
Intente buscar documentación sobre el BIRT y no encontré demasiada, si alguno tiene algunos links lo agradecería.